# how to get value from param URL mountebank?

Tags: mountebank

I have tried use **inject** to get param URL request like below

> http://api.com?param1=test&param2=test2

I try to get param2 value :

```
var full_url = request.path;
var param2 = full_url.searchParams.get('param2');
```

but i can't get fullpath of URL i got only

> http://api.com

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at request.**query**

Try accessing request.query.param2 instead.

```
var full_url = request.path;
var param2 = request.query.param2;
```